# Are conditions for raising "potentially dangerous Request.Form value" errors dependent on .NET configuration and version?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, blogengine.net

I'm testing a Tiny_MCE plugin for [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) extension I wrote earlier and I keep receiving the following error message whenever I use my own extension or the extremely popular SyntaxHighlighter extension which both have similar behaviors and both implement Tiny_MCE plugins:

> Url :
> 'http://localhost/admin/Pages/Add_entry.aspx'
>
> Raw Url : /admin/Pages/Add_entry.aspx
>
> Message : A potentially dangerous
> Request.Form value was detected from
> the client
> (ctl00$cphAdmin$txtContent$TinyMCE1$txtContent="
>
> Source : System.WebStackTrace :    at
> System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String
> value, String collectionKey,
> RequestValidationSource
> requestCollection)   at
> System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection
> nvc, RequestValidationSource
> requestCollection)   at
> System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()   at
> System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Item(String
> key)   at
> BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.CompressionModule.context_PostReleaseRequestState(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) in
> D:\Projects\Be-1610\BlogEngine\DotNetSlave.BusinessLogic\Web\HttpModules\CompressionModule.cs:line
> 62   at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean&
> completedSynchronously)TargetSite :
> Void ValidateString(System.String,
> System.String,
> System.Web.Util.RequestValidationSource)

My question is thus: although I receive this error on my local environment (IIS 7.5 ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated App Pool) I receive no error whatsoever on my live environment (IIS 7.5 ASP.NET 3.5 SP1/ 3.0 / 2.0.) Additionally whenever I test the extension using debug mode in Visual Studio 2010 and run the site off of a separate instance I don't receive this error.

I'm almost certain that the fact that this issue only occurs on my localhost IIS instance indicates that it's a configuration issue or a behavior specific to ASP.NET 4.0, but I don't know what exactly. Do any of you know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you see it as an error now is because of .NET 4.0.  This was a breaking change in ASP.NET 4.0 and is described [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147).

Fastest was to revert is to add this to your web.config:

`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Specific to BlogEngine.NET, I liked [this blog entry](http://www.rajbandi.net/ASPNet-40-BlogEngineNet-A-potentially-dangerous-RequestForm-value) that suggested adding this element to the Admin Web.Config, rather than the main Web.Config.

Answer (score 5):

It's telling you that a control (such as a text input) is returning something that looks like HTML or javascript, and that it's not going to assume you're sanitizing your inputs.

Of course, since you *are* being paranoid about your inputs (you *are*, aren't you?) you can turn that warning off.

How to turn it off for that page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" ValidateRequest="false" [etc]
```

To turn it off for the whole site, put this in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    [etc.]
```

Comment: I understand that - but why does it only raise this issue under this particular configuration and not the others? The codebase is the same between all of the other instances - only a connection string in the web.config file and the other IIS settings are different.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb.  Because those are not the only variations in your configuration.  If you haven't specified the validateRequest=false in your web.config, it is then dependent on the settings in the (for example) enterprise.config and machine.config files for the framework version you are using.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this as the best answer because even though it doesn't truly address the spirit of my question, it still provides a couple of work-arounds. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is no solution anymore for .net 4.0: `The request validation settings of the pages element (if any) in the configuration file or of the @ Page directive in an individual page are ignored.` link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE I believe has a way to encode the content that it submits to the server. Check that out and this message will go away. Because what @egrunin said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically because , user might have posted some data in html tag form or tiny-mce is posting data in html forms. Try looking for properties that will return plain text from the editor. Also you can try above if it solves your issue.